# How to make sense of LowpassFilter, SampleRate and the cutoff frequency ωc in different Mathematica versions?

Tags: filtering, signal-processing

How do you make sense of the scale of "time" and "sampling" when using [`LowpassFilter`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/LowpassFilter.html) and [`SampleRate`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SampleRate.html) ?

Given the test data with components at ***1Hz*** and ***5Hz***

```
data1 = Array[N[Sin[2 Pi #] + Sin[2 Pi 5 #]] &, 100, {-1, 1}];
```

I expect to apply a low-pass filter at ***2Hz*** and ***10Hz***

```
data2 = N @ LowpassFilter[data1, 2, SampleRate -> 50];

data3 = N @ LowpassFilter[data1, 10, SampleRate -> 50];
```

And see that `data3` contains a significant part of the ***5Hz*** component.

What am I doing wrong here?

In Win7 64 and *Mathematica* 10.2 and 10.1 I get

```
ListPlot[
  {
   data1
   , data2
   , data3
   }
  , Joined -> True
  , PlotRange -> {-2, 2}
  , PlotStyle -> {Gray, Red, Blue}
  ]
```

[image]

while versions 9.0 and 10.0 behave differently.

[image]

Should I understand that these new versions have a bug?

Comment: Results from v9 : ![Mathematica graphics](http://i.stack.imgur.com/h8mPn.png)

Comment: I get belisarius' result on 10.0.1, OSX.

Comment: @belisarius,  get your result in 9.0, 10.0, and mine in 10.1 and 10.2.

Comment: @rhermans Should we add a `Version10` tag then?

Comment: Not a problem in Version 10.0.1, as reported by @N.J.Evans, so no, unless there is a `Version10.1` tag

Comment: Reported to Wolfram Technical Support [CASE:3394681], but I'm not discarding the possibility that I'm understanding the problem wrongly. The difference in behaviour may be a fix, instead of a bug.

Comment: I get the same result as @rhermans in 10.2, but these results all seem correct to me. The issue (to me, it would seem) is that $\omega_c$ is an angular frequency, so $f_c=\omega_c/(2\pi)$. I think the difference people are getting between 10.0 and 10.1/10.2 arises from different filtering techniques. Try: `data2 = N@LowpassFilter[data1, Quantity[2, "Hertz"], SampleRate -> 50];
data3 = N@
   LowpassFilter[data1, Quantity[10, "Hertz"], SampleRate -> 50];` and that looks to give the correct result.

Comment: @MichaelWitt I think you have nailed it. Thanks, that does solve the problem. Probably you could post it as an answer? Still, the change in behaviour doesn't seem to be properly documented.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It looks like your problem comes from the fact that $\omega_c$ will be referring to an *angular* frequency, so $$\omega_c=2\pi f_c$$
Therefore, you can get the desired result by changing your `data2` and `data3` definitions:

```
data2 = N@LowpassFilter[data1, 2*Pi*2, SampleRate -> 50];
data3 = N@LowpassFilter[data1, 2*Pi*10, SampleRate -> 50];
```

Alternatively, you can define it in terms of Hz:

```
data2 = N@LowpassFilter[data1, Quantity[2, "Hertz"], SampleRate -> 50];
data3 = N@LowpassFilter[data1, Quantity[10, "Hertz"], SampleRate -> 50];
```

And you get

[image: Filter Response]

Finally, the difference people seem to be getting in pre-10.1 and 10.1/10.2 seems to be different filter types. Specifying `LowpassFilter` will use whatever lowpass filter Wolfram has programmed in. It wouldn't surprise me to see them change the filter type, if it made sense to them, especially since there are other functions like `ButterworthFilterModel` that can be used for specifying the filter type explicitly.